# Query to DB2 using created connection string

Tags: python-2.7, db2, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a way how to validate if the connection string is correct. Aim to get data from selected tables on our DB2 and pull them to generate data or simply to have a multiples queries

Here is my initial connection string:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://db2inst1:secret@host.name.com:50000/pydev')
```

Any code suggestion that I can start up how to query a data from the tables using DB2.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string needs a specific list of parts to be correct. T[he components depend on how you connect to Db2 and what type of Db2](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdbsa/tree/master/ibm_db_sa). The port may be a standard port (50000) or an entirely different one. Thus, if you know what should be the required parts, you could use a REGEX expression to check for those patterns.

However, if you mean to check for "is this a valid connection string", then my take is that you cannot check and be entirely sure that it may connect to Db2.